# How to create a URL with parameter in the path in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following route:

```
get 'event/check_in/:event_date_id' => 'event#check_in'
```

I want to provide a link to it:

```
event_check_in_path(event_date_id: event_date.id)
```

I was hoping to get this:

```
/event/check_in/5
```

Instead I got this:

```
/event/check_in?event_date_id=5
```

What's the proper way to do this in Rails (using latest version of 4.1)?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something off with your routes. If you have an `event` resource, you should map your route as such `/event/5/check_in`, so you would have something looking like this in routes:

```
resources :event do
  patch :check_in, on: :member
end
```

This should give you a `check_in_event_path`. You can then just pass the event to the path:

```
check_in_event_path(@event)
```

Comment: in my case, event is not a resource. It's just a path.

Comment: @at. surely you have an events resource? If not, just define a normal path then. I don't see anything particularly complicated about what you are trying to do. I suggest you read the Rails Routing in Rails guides. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

To generate the route you want, send your event_date_id as a formal parameter instead:

`event_checkin_path(event_date.id)` => `event/checkin/7`

Path helpers take an optional hash of additional named parameters, but, as you noticed, these are added to the generated URL as query parameters:

`event_checkin_path(event_date.id, other_param: "foo")` => `event/checkin/7?other_param=foo`

Comment: I should've put in my question that I had tried this. What happens is the path becomes `/event/check_in.7` I want the period to be a `/`

Comment: Try also declaring your route as `get 'event/check_in/:event_date_id' => 'event#check_in', as: :event_checkin` -- confirmed to work as above with Rails 4.1.5.

Comment: ... and if that doesn't work, run `rake routes` and include the output here.

Answer (score 0):

```
#config/routes.rb
scope module: "event" do 
   get "check_in/:event_date_id", to: "event#check_in", as: :check_in
end
```

This should allow you to call:

```
<%= link_to "Event", event_check_in_path(event_date.id) %>
```